# Method resolution in Comparer

Tags: c#, overloading, derived

consider the following basic class layout:

```
public class Base : IComparable<Base>
{
  public int CompareTo(Base other)
  {
    //Do comparison
  }
}

public class Derived : Base, IComparable<Derived>
{
  public int CompareTo(Derived other)
  {
    //Do comparison
  }  
}

public class BaseComparer : IComparer<Base>
{
  public int Compare(Base x, Base y)
  {
   return x.CompareTo(y);
  }
}
```

and then using those as follows:

```
List<Base> thingies = new List<Base>
{
  new Base(),
  new Derived(),
  new Derived()
};

thingies.Sort(new BaseComparer());
```

I was expecting the Comparer to be calling the Derived.CompareTo method in those situations where both it's x and y parameters are Derived instances.

However, this is not the case and Base.CompareTo is called instead and I keep wondering why. I can't seem to deduct this behaviour with my basic understanding of the overload resolution rules as described in the C# language specification.

Can someone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Read Eric Lipperts blog posts about overload resolution - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/overload+resolution/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Base` knows nothing of its derived classes – so in `Base` there’s only *one* `CompareTo` method, and that gets called unconditionally.

The point is that overload resolution happens at *compile time* where there’s no information about the actual type of `Base` references available. You need to *override* the method in `Derived`, not *overload* it:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
  public override int CompareTo(Base other)
  {
    //Do comparison
  }  
}
```

And additionally mark the `Base.CompareTo` method `virtual`.

Notice that this doesn’t implement `IComparable<Derived>` any more. You can *also* do this, but for your purpose that’s unrelated.

Comment: Thanx for your effort. I was trying to be clever and prevent the virtual/override implementation on CompareTo(Base) by using the overload for the specific scenario where both x and y are Derived instances. Seems I was not so clever after all :)

Answer (score 1):

Overload resolution is not what's happening here. You've got two independent methods: their full names are `IComparable<Base>.CompareTo` and `IComparable<Derived>.CompareTo`.

The only one that `BaseComparer` knows how to call is `IComparable<Base>.CompareTo`. It knows nothing about `IComparable<Derived>`.

In your application, does it make sense to compare a `Base` with a `Derived` -- that is, can say that a `Base` comes before or after a `Derived`?

- If so, you'd be better of to stay with only `IComparable<Base>`, or even the non-generic `IComparable`, and be prepared to check types in subclasses
- If not, you should consider making `Base` abstract, and only implementing `IComparable<T>` on leaf classes

Comment: So I see now. In my case it makes sense to compare Base and Derived instances. I was trying to be clever and only have to a write a separate CompareTo implementation in the case where a more subtle comparison must take place (that is, where both are Derived instances) and for all other scenarios simply let overload resolution fall back on the sufficient comparison in Base.CompareTo. Alas... :)

Answer (score 1):

`IComparable<Base>` and `IComparable<Derived>` are two different types, so two methods `CompareTo` in `Derived` are mapped onto two different slots. `CompareTo` invoked by `BaseComparer` calls method of `IComparable<Base>`. You can denote `CompareTo(Base)` in `Base` as `virtual` and override it in `Derived` to get (partially) expected behavior.

```
public class Base : IComparable<Base>
{
    public virtual int CompareTo(Base other)
    {
        // do comparison
    }
}

public class Derived : Base, IComparable<Derived>
{
    public int CompareTo(Derived other)
    {
        // do comparison
    }

    public override int CompareTo(Base other)
    {
        if (other is Derived)
            return CompareTo((Derived) other);
        return base.CompareTo(other);
    }
}
```